# Wrong Mesh Collider Size for Procedurally Generated Mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, mesh

I am trying to create a simple mesh through code and trying to give a simple mesh collider the same size as the mesh. I tried many different things, however mesh collider always appears to be bigger than the mesh itself. I am really confused, can anyone solve the problem or point me in the right direction? Any help is appreciated.

Here is the screenshot of what's happening:
[image: Problem]

Also, here is the code:

```
public class PolygonGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Mesh mesh;
    public List<Vector3> newVertices = new List<Vector3>();
    public List<int> newTriangles = new List<int>();
    private MeshCollider meshCol;
    public List<Vector3> colVertices = new List<Vector3> ();
    public List<int> colTriangles = new List<int> ();

    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter> ().mesh;
        meshCol = gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(MeshCollider)) as MeshCollider;
        meshCol.convex = true;


        x = this.gameObject.transform.position.x;
        y = this.gameObject.transform.position.y;
        z = this.gameObject.transform.position.z;

        GenSquare (x, y);
        GenCollider (x, y);

        UpdateMesh ();
    }

    void UpdateMesh()
    {
        mesh.Clear ();
        mesh.vertices = newVertices.ToArray();
        mesh.triangles = newTriangles.ToArray();
        mesh.Optimize ();
        mesh.RecalculateNormals ();

        Mesh newMesh = new Mesh ();
        newMesh.vertices = colVertices.ToArray ();
        newMesh.triangles = colTriangles.ToArray ();
        meshCol.sharedMesh = newMesh;
    }

    void GenSquare(float x, float y)
    {
        newVertices.Add( new Vector3 (x  , y  , z ));
        newVertices.Add( new Vector3 (x + 1 , y  , z ));
        newVertices.Add( new Vector3 (x + 1 , y-1 , z ));
        newVertices.Add( new Vector3 (x  , y-1 , z ));

        newTriangles.Add(0);
        newTriangles.Add(2);
        newTriangles.Add(3);
        newTriangles.Add(0);
        newTriangles.Add(1);
        newTriangles.Add(2);
    }

    void GenCollider( float x, float y)
    {
        colVertices.Add( new Vector3 (x  , y  , z));
        colVertices.Add( new Vector3 (x + 1 , y  , z));
        colVertices.Add( new Vector3 (x + 1 , y-1  , z ));
        colVertices.Add( new Vector3 (x  , y-1  , z ));

        colTriangles.Add (0);
        colTriangles.Add (2);
        colTriangles.Add (3);
        colTriangles.Add (0);
        colTriangles.Add (1);
        colTriangles.Add (2);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        Debug.Log("Collision");

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Trigger");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you do not have to create a collider manually. You should be able to addcomponent to the gameobject you create with your mesh, and it should calculate the collider for you. But if you still want to create it manually, I think the collider normally is 10 times larger than the mesh in world scale. So the size of the collider should be divided by 10.

This should fix it:

```
void GenCollider( float x, float y)
{
    colVertices.Add( new Vector3 (x  , y  , z));
    colVertices.Add( new Vector3 (x + 0.1f , y  , z));
    colVertices.Add( new Vector3 (x + 0.1f , y-0.1f  , z ));
    colVertices.Add( new Vector3 (x  , y-0.1f  , z ));

    colTriangles.Add (0);
    colTriangles.Add (2);
    colTriangles.Add (3);
    colTriangles.Add (0);
    colTriangles.Add (1);
    colTriangles.Add (2);
}
```

I'm not 100 percent certain, so please let me know if you try it.

Comment: I have tried it. It is not 10 times larger but it is 2 times larger; thus, using 0.5f for the values gets me the correct collider size. However, even though i get the correct size, position of the collider is wrong as well. You are right that it creates a collider automatically and that was the problem for me. After spending more time on it I have kind of found the problem and fixed it. Problem comes with using it as a convex collider. If i don't use convex collider Unity gives me error saying that i cannot use collider, if i make it convex it creates a bigger collider at a wrong position.

Comment: However, the collider it creates is 3d as opposed to the 2d manual collider i am trying to create. So, I decided to create a 3d collider rather than a 2d collider with a very thin border. After converting my collider to 3d, Unity now sees it as a convex collider and lets me keep my collider, which solves the problem for me now. I am still curious to find out the behaviour why can't I use a 2d mesh collider and why doesn't unity recognizes 2d mesh collider as a convex shape. Isn't it convex? And why does it make the collider size larger than the shape when creating the collider itself?

Comment: Oh wow, I did not know that you were working with 2D. I think your problem here is that MeshCollider is a 3D collider, I think you might want to use PolygonCollider2D. That might be the equivalent of MeshCollider for 2D programming.

Comment: You were completely right. I thought Meshes as part of 3D space and I thought I should use a 3D collider with it. But i was generating a 2d mesh, and did not know I could attach a PolygonCollider2D to it; I thought PolygonCollider2D's are only to be used with the sprites. Thanks for helping me to figure out the problem, greatly appreciated. To make a PolygonColider2D for my meshes I have benefited from the script in this page http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/solved-draw-polygon2d-collider-paths-around-a-2d-mesh.334039/ greatly; thus, I am posting it here for future reference.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of service :) Thank you for posting the link here, it's very thoughtful of you